# how to write multiple reusable global functions in nodered

Tags: node-red

How to store multiple function node globally stored in one single node,
and invoke it from wherever required as an reusable function?
Is it like this? But how to store multiple function?

Comment: Perhaps a few use-case examples of what you want to accomplish? What have you already tried? Have you read the [Global Context](https://nodered.org/docs/writing-functions#global-context) docs?

Comment: Folks, please don't vote down questions without giving people a chance to improve them. Add a comment with suggestions and give them time to respond. Not everyone knows what good questions look like and we all had to start somewhere.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a sub-flow to achieve this. Simply put a function node inside a sub-flow and use the sub-flow wherever you need to.

Alternatively, you could use the global variables part of the `settings.js` file to store a function. You could then access that in any function node simply by assigning it to a local variable within a function node. You may wish to create a Node.js module if you consider this option as this is how Node.js is designed to work.

Finally, if the code is complex enough to warrant it, you could consider creating a custom node.

Answer (score 3):

I am not entirely sure this is what you are asking, but I have found a way to define "global" functions in a node and invoke the full set of them from any other function node. I will call it a *library* of custom functions.

It needs a small dirty-trick in order to work, but it does very well.

[image: Node-RED flow for global functions library]

In the first function node, "define global_functions", you need to define your custom functions. It needs to be called at least once, before any node requiring your library:

```
var global_functions = {
    load_global_functions: function(){

        test1 = function(){
            return "Test 1!";
        }

        test2 = function(){
            return "Test 2!";
        }
        
        return this;
    }
};
flow.set("global_functions", global_functions);
```

Of course, you can use **global** context instead of **flow** context if you prefer to share the functions across all flows.

In any function node requiring the library, you just need to load it before using any of your custom functions:

```
// Load global functions
eval("lgf="+String(flow.get("global_functions").load_global_functions)+";lgf();");

// Run a custom function. Send the result to debug sidebar
node.warn(test1());
```

You can see the result in the debug sidebar of the screenshot above.

This is my dirty trick: for some reason you cannot simply run `flow.get("global_functions").load_global_functions();`, so I managed to use an eval, which proved a nice workaround this time. If you can find a better way, please feel free to share.

Here you have the full working example:

```
[{"id":"7aa9f6da.a3eeb8","type":"tab","label":"Global functions","disabled":false,"info":""},{"id":"8c828716.143678","type":"inject","z":"7aa9f6da.a3eeb8","name":"manual","props":[{"p":"payload","v":"","vt":"date"},{"p":"topic","v":"","vt":"string"}],"repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"onceDelay":"3","topic":"","payload":"","payloadType":"date","x":110,"y":40,"wires":[["b7263482.6356b8"]]},{"id":"b7263482.6356b8","type":"function","z":"7aa9f6da.a3eeb8","name":"define global_functions","func":"var global_functions = {\n\tload_global_functions: function(){\n\n\t\ttest1 = function(){\n\t\t\treturn \"Test 1!\";\n\t\t}\n\n\t\ttest2 = function(){\n\t\t\treturn \"Test 2!\";\n\t\t}\n\t\t\n    \treturn this;\n\t}\n};\nflow.set(\"global_functions\", global_functions);\n","outputs":0,"noerr":0,"initialize":"","finalize":"","x":300,"y":40,"wires":[]},{"id":"ab941f1f.f5ac9","type":"inject","z":"7aa9f6da.a3eeb8","name":"manual","props":[{"p":"payload","v":"","vt":"date"},{"p":"topic","v":"","vt":"string"}],"repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"onceDelay":"3","topic":"","payload":"","payloadType":"date","x":110,"y":100,"wires":[["88f03f79.ac9d4"]]},{"id":"88f03f79.ac9d4","type":"function","z":"7aa9f6da.a3eeb8","name":"call test1()","func":"// Load global functions\n//flow.get(\"global_functions\").load_global_functions();\neval(\"lgf=\"+String(flow.get(\"global_functions\").load_global_functions)+\";lgf();\");\n\nnode.warn(test1());","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"initialize":"","finalize":"","x":270,"y":100,"wires":[[]]}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Building from @Kar.ma 's answer, I cleaned up the function definitions a bit so there's no need for the eval() at all.  This seems similar to the answer by @ihtus as well.

```
var global_functions = {
    "test1": function(){
        return "Test 1!";
    }
    , "test2": function(){
        return "Test 2!";
    }
};
flow.set("global_functions", global_functions);
```

Followed by:

```
const g = flow.get("global_functions");
node.warn(g.test1());
```

The only reason I would be concerned with this solution is if there's a specific reason that @Kar.ma needed the definition and the loading separate.

And here's the import for the flow.

```
[{"id":"7aa9f6da.a3eeb8","type":"tab","label":"Global functions","disabled":false,"info":""},{"id":"8c828716.143678","type":"inject","z":"7aa9f6da.a3eeb8","name":"manual","props":[{"p":"payload","v":"","vt":"date"},{"p":"topic","v":"","vt":"string"}],"repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"onceDelay":"3","topic":"","payload":"","payloadType":"date","x":110,"y":40,"wires":[["b7263482.6356b8"]]},{"id":"b7263482.6356b8","type":"function","z":"7aa9f6da.a3eeb8","name":"define global_functions","func":"var global_functions = {\n\t\"test1\": function(){\n\t\treturn \"Test 1!\";\n\t}\n\n\t, \"test2\": function(){\n\t\treturn \"Test 2!\";\n\t}\n};\nflow.set(\"global_functions\", global_functions);\n","outputs":0,"noerr":0,"initialize":"","finalize":"","libs":[],"x":300,"y":40,"wires":[]},{"id":"ab941f1f.f5ac9","type":"inject","z":"7aa9f6da.a3eeb8","name":"manual","props":[{"p":"payload","v":"","vt":"date"},{"p":"topic","v":"","vt":"string"}],"repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"onceDelay":"3","topic":"","payload":"","payloadType":"date","x":110,"y":100,"wires":[["88f03f79.ac9d4"]]},{"id":"88f03f79.ac9d4","type":"function","z":"7aa9f6da.a3eeb8","name":"call test1()","func":"const g = flow.get(\"global_functions\");\nnode.warn(g.test1());\n","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"initialize":"","finalize":"","libs":[],"x":270,"y":100,"wires":[[]]}]
```

Answer (score 1):

My problem is the need for a js function library, re-used in many node-red function nodes, in many large flows.
copy/paste is NOT a solution - it's a maintenance nightmare.

I [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49125059/how-to-pass-parameters-to-an-eval-based-function-injavascript) a  way to use functions stored in a JSON string. I use for that the `global.myfunctions`, stored in a `node-red-contrib-config` node: now it is a real '*JSON object*' in OO sense, with attributes (some other const) and methods. This solution is not perfect, not fast, requires in any node both `myfunctions`  and the following function (`_callJSONMethod`) to call the methods, the methods cannot call each other...  But it works!.

Example in `global.myfunctions` (node-red-contrib-config) (note: all in one line)

```
{
    "_getHello":"function(friend){return(\"Hi \"+friend);}"
}
```

How to use it in a 'function' node:

```
// local function requred to access `myfunctions`:
function _callJSONMethod(obj, fname, a, b, c, d) {
    var wrap = s => "{ return " + obj[fname] + " };"    // return the block having function expression
        var func = new Function(wrap(obj[fname]));      // ignore the node-red ⚠ warning
    return func.call(null).call(obj, a, b, c, d);       // invoke the function using arguments
}

var myfunctions = global.get("myfunctions");
.......
var message = _callJSONMethod(myfunctions, "_getHello", "George");
.......
```

This strategy solves many problems, the principal is to have only one version of the code! Other advantages:

- No special operations are required to the user when it imports my flows.
- Only one file for main-flow and libraries, thank the 'config' node.
- *note: the debug in the JSON form is quasi impossible. To do changes, extract the code and use it in a standard js function. (`notePad++` can help you)*

Answer (score 1):

https://discourse.nodered.org/t/importing-function-from-another-node/15885/6

offers is a solution for this.

You can apply it by using

```
let util = global.get("util")["add"]
console.log(util(1,2))
```

I am defining the global functions in a function node on the first flow using the "Start" property.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it works for me:

**1)** Function node called 'Global Functions', with 'On Start' code

```
var glb_func = {
  my_func : function (param) {
  ...
  return result;
  }
};
global.set("glb_func", glb_func);
```

**2)** Function node called 'Init lib' (located on any flow), with 'On Start' code

```
var glb_func = global.get("glb_func");
var res = glb_func.my_func();
```