# How to pass parameters to an eval based function inJavascript

Tags: javascript, parameter-passing, eval

I am storing function body in string with function name.

```
function fnRandom(lim){
    var data=[];
    for(var i=0;i<lim;i++)
    {
        data=data.concat(Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1));
    }
return data;
}
```

After selecting the functionName from a drop down I use eval to execute function body.

```
JSON.stringify(eval(this.selectedFunction.body));
```

I want to pass *'lim'* to this execution or can I use functionName as initiating point for execution somehow?

Comment: Use `Function` constructor instead.

Comment: Function(this.selectedFunction.body) gives function anonymous(){} around the  actual function and my problem is related to passing the data to this function

Comment: Does `this.selectedFunction` include any information about the parameters? If not, this will be difficult, because there's no way to know which undeclared variables in the body are parameters versus global variables.

Comment: Actually it does need to validate parameters ; maybe I should send a Json object and process on that

Comment: How to do it the way function node of NODE-RED does. Anyone has idea about it?

Answer (score 22):

Use [Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) constructor

```js
var body = "console.log(arguments)"

var func = new Function( body );
func.call( null, 1, 2 ); //invoke the function using arguments
```

**with named parameters**

```js
var body = "function( a, b ){ console.log(a, b) }"
var wrap = s => "{ return " + body + " };" //return the block having function expression
var func = new Function( wrap(body) );
func.call( null ).call( null, 1, 2  ); //invoke the function using arguments
```

Comment: You didn't specify any arguments in the `new Function()` call.

Comment: This only works if the function uses `arguments` instead of named parameters.

Comment: @Barmar yes, I have added a version with named parameters as well.

Comment: Your function body is the whole function, not just the body.

Comment: If function is only body in OP's case, then named parameters cannot be used since we don't know the names of parameters used in the body

Comment: I know, I wrote that in a comment above. I think he has a design problem that makes this impossible to solve in a general way.

Answer (score 11):

Eval evaluates whatever you give it to and returns even a function.

```
var x = eval('(y)=>y+1');
x(3) // return 4
```

So you can use it like this:

```
var lim = 3;
var body = 'return lim+1;';
JSON.stringify(eval('(lim) => {' + body + '}')(lim)); //returns "4"
```

Another way using Function:

```
var lim = 3;
JSON.stringify((new Function('lim', this.selectedFunction.body))(lim));
```

Comment: he only has the function body, not the whole function.

Comment: What if the parameter isn't named `lim`?

Comment: He has to know how his parameters have to be named in his body-strings. Otherwise @gurvinder372 's answer will suit better.

Comment: Yes, I think he has some fundamental design problems because of that. A solution like this doesn't work with arbitrary functions. He really needs to store more information in `this.selectedFunction` than just the body.

Comment: I fully agree with you

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Function object.

```js
var param1 = 666;
var param2 = 'ABC';
var dynamicJS = 'return `Param1 = ${param1}, Param2 = ${param2}`';
var func = new Function('param1', 'param2', dynamicJS);
var result = func(param1, param2);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using vuejs, so the code will be like this

```
getTargetfunction(funcN, o_id, i_id) {
            console.log(funcN, o_id, i_id);
            const x = o_id;
            const y = i_id;
            eval("this." + funcN + "(x,y)");
        },
```

in the [developer mozilla eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)

> Indirect eval works in the global scope rather than the local scope, and the code being evaluated doesn't have access to local variables within the scope where it's being called.

```
  function test() {
  const x = 2;
  const y = 4;
  // Direct call, uses local scope
  console.log(eval("x + y")); // Result is 6
  console.log(eval?.("x + y")); // Uses global scope, throws because x is undefined
}
```