# Save JavaScript script text string as function variable to call it

Tags: javascript, fetch, eval, script-tag

I am fetching a JS script from a server, and getting the following string back:

```
(function(e){function t(t){for(var r,a,o=t[0],c=t[1] .....
```

I want to save it as a function variable so I can call it (and pass an argument).

I tried wrapping the string with a `return` (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49125126)) and then use `Function()` constructor to call it in order get the original function, but it returns `undefined`.

How can I do this?

Comment: It looks like the code is wrapped in an IIFE, which probably means you can only save the return value to a variable, but not the function itself.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try eval [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval](http://eval)

eval is a function that evaluates even if it is a function in string

something like this

```
const yourVariable = eval("function fromServerResponse(){console.log('executed');}")
```

Comment: Yes, I'm getting `Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Illegal return statement` exception. Also, I prefer to not use `eval` if possible.